# Changing Violin tab to Guitar tab

Tags: guitar

I want you to tell me how I change Violin tab to Guitar tab? can you show me an example? there are a lot of Violin tabs(songs) in my country but I can't to use them for Guitar because guitar is a new musical instruments here...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify that you really mean violin *tabs* (e.g. http://nativeground.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/pretty-polly.png) ?

Comment: I can only assume the problem the OP is refering to is that since a violin has strings tuned in perfect fifths rather than perfect fourths like a guitar and has a lowest note of G rather than A, you can't write a guitar melody onto violin tab and expect it to still be correct.

Comment: @TimHargreaves that's what I initially assumed, but (the other) Tim and I were wondering if by 'Violin tab' the OP really means SN (as while there are such things as violin tabs, SN is much more common in most parts)

Comment: As someone who has used both violin tab and guitar tab, I can't think of any trick that would help. I think you'll have to translate the violin tab to the actual notes, then translate those notes to guitar tab. If you need this written, it may mean learning standard notation, but you at least need the names of the notes as written in each form of notation. Then when  you know it's an open E on the violin tab, you can write it as a high E in guitar tab.

Comment: Can you show an example of your violin tab? I've seen more than one version.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option I believe is to use tuxguitar. You have to edit track properties. Change them to Violin tuning. No you can write tab inside program. After finishing again change tuning back to guitar and ensure **transpose affected notes** is checked. You should have the guitar tab now.  [image: track properties]

This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHGtJFpE4D4) may be helpful in learning tux guitar in general

Answer (score 0):

There is also a lot of proper violin music available, so it is just as well to learn to play guitar using real music. It's just another skill, a different (and probably far more useful) one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what the OP is asking although I can't be sure.

Violin tabs and guitar tabs are both real and valid staffs but they are not transferable. This is because they have different tunings.

A guitar tab will go as follows:

E (High)
B
G
D
A
E (Low)

As you can see the strings ascend in perfect fourths (5 semitones)

A violin tab will go like this:

E (High)
A
D
G (Low)

Note that this is the opposite order to the guitar. This is because the violin strings ascend in perfect **fifths** (7 semitones).

The means that you can't simply play violin tabs as if they were guitar or bass tabs or vice versa because they have different intervals between strings and different starting notes.

It is possible to rewrite one as the other but this is not easy without basic knowledge of music theory.